# Generate YML file from YML.dist

Tags: php, yaml, silex, symfony-components

I'm building my own micro-framework using Silex and I can't solve one problem: how can I autogenerate ***parameters.yml*** file from ***.dist file*** when **composer install** command is run (like in Symfony)?

What packages or components should I use? 
Tnx

Comment: Symfony uses [Incenteev/ParameterHandler/Processor](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler/blob/master/Processor.php) to achieve what you are describing. You may want to study this particular file to understand what it does and implement this functionnality, if not the bundle itself.

Comment: Could also hook the composer process(es) and run a terminal command when post-autoload-generate or other have been triggered.

Comment: thanks for you're advice, it was very helpful:) I spent about month to find solution in Google and you help me in 5 minutes :D